# Escape output, not filter the input?

Tags: php

I want to know if it's safe to store data received from $_POST, $_GET without cleaning them before inserting into the database, only performing some validation to check if the content is in the expected format. For example, I have a comment system, and these comments cannot exceed 3000 characters, so I validate to ensure the comment is not empty or longer than 3000 characters. When needed, I also validate to see if it's an integer, email, or URL, but I never filter the input using filters like 'FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING' because they erase part of the content. I directly insert the values from $_POST or $_GET into the database using PDO.

**An example of how I'm doing it, I'd like to know if it's safe.**

```
<?
include_once('connection.php');

//Pre validation
$comment = isset($_POST['comment']) ? $_POST['comment'] : null;

if(empty($comment)){
    echo json_encode( ['error' => 'This is empty']);
    die();
}

if(mb_strlen($comment, 'UTF-8') > 3000){
    echo json_encode( ['error' => 'Very big']);
    die();
}

// Insert
$insert = sql($db, "INSERT INTO comments(comment) VALUES (?)", array($comment), "lastid");

// Select
$query = sql($db, "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id = ?", array($insert), "rows");

echo htmlspecialchars($query['comment'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

**connection.php**

```
<?
define("HOST", 'localhost');
define("USER", 'root');
define("PASS", '32Tx89,ccclkt80@');
define("NAME", 'mydb');

//try connect
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".HOST.";dbname=".NAME.";charset=utf8mb4", "".USER."", "".PASS."");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Error connecting to database");
}

function sql($db, $q, $params, $return) {
    
    try {

        //prepare the query
        $stmt = $db->prepare($q);

        //execute
        $stmt->execute($params);
        
        // returns in the format requested by the variable "$return"
        if ($return == "rows") {
            return $stmt->fetch();
        }elseif ($return == "rowsall") {
            return $stmt->fetchAll();
        }elseif ($return == "count") {
            return $stmt->rowCount();
        }elseif( $return == "lastid"){
            return $db->lastInsertId();
        }
        
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
        
        echo "DataBase Error: ".$e->getMessage();
        error_log($e->getMessage());
        die();
        
    }catch(Exception $e) {
        
        echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
        error_log($e->getMessage());
        die();
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is safe and how it should be done. Validate on input, use parameters for SQL, escape any data on output depends on the media type.

Comment: On a side note, remove that try ... catch ... die sequence, [this is not how it should be done](https://www.phpdelusions.net/basic_principles_of_web_programming#error_reporting). And your sql() function is good but can be made much simpler and powerful. Make it return a statement and instead of that last parameter you'll be able to chain any function you need, $data = sql($db, $sql, $params)->fetchAll();` which is cleaner and [much more powerful](https://www.phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#best)